# Сборка в "чистой архитектуре"

Tags: java, android, gradle

Приложение состоит из 3х пакетов:

- **Presentation** (Содержит зависимости андроид API)
- **Data** (На чистой джаве, без андроидных зависимостей, отвечает за работу с сервером)
- **Domain**

Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы при сборке того(или иного) варианта, менялся адрес API к которой мы обращаемся.

В первом пакете, мы можем создать в `buidl.gradle` `buildVariants->productFlavors` (меняем `applicationId` и все заработает).

Но эти варианты сборки не действуют на пакет **Data**.
Что делать?

```
Presentation(Имеет зависимость от Domain)
src-
    main-java
    stage-java


Domain(Имеет зависимость от Data)

Data(На чистой джаве, нет зависимостей андроида)
src-    
    main-java-Const->www.adders.com
    stage-java-Const->www.stage.adderss.com
```

Когда я меняю в **Presentation** `productFravors`, модуль **Data** игнорирует это.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы модуль **Data** собирался в разные варианты.

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать так, если я правильно конечно понял вопрос.

```
productFlavors {

    target1 {
        applicationId "com.target1"
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '\"http://baseurl1.com/\"'
    }

    target2 {
        applicationId "com.target2"
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '\"http://baseurl2.com/\"'
    }

}
```

а затем в вашем Data классе использовать BuilConfig.BASE_URL. При смене таргета, урл поменяется на соответствующий.

Comment: В пакете presentation  я именно так и делаю.  Только без BuildConfig, т.к. BuildConfig для каждого пакета уникален. И если я базовый урл в перезнейшн указываю, то в пакете дата об этом ничего не известно

Comment: Я обновил вопрос